# extracting the nth column of each row of a DT in R where n is a vector of the number of rows in the DT

Tags: r, data.table

Seems silly but a simple extraction from a DT is giving me problems.
Consider a toy example:
Create a test data.table with 5 columns:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("  
            V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
            1 10  7  4  3
            2 11  8  5  2
            3 12  9  6  1
            4  1 10  7  4
            5  2 11  8  4
            6  3 12  9  3
            7  4  1 10  3
            8  5  2 11  1
            9  6  3 12  2")
```

Now I want to add a 6th column V6 that contains the value of the column with column number in V5, for each row. So the **final** output I need is a `data.table` that transforms dt to below:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1:  1 10  7  4  3  7
2:  2 11  8  5  2 11
3:  3 12  9  6  1  3
4:  4  1 10  7  4  7
5:  5  2 11  8  4  8
6:  6  3 12  9  3 12
7:  7  4  1 10  3  1
8:  8  5  2 11  1  8
9:  9  6  3 12  2  6
```

Comment: I think instead of `runif` you meant `sample(4, 9, replace = TRUE)`? Otherwise your example isn't reproducible

Comment: Yes @DavidArenburg you are right. I will remove `runif()` and just leave it with the data.table values. Will that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can loop through the rows, subset the `.SD` based on the column index in 'V5' and assign (`:=` it to create 'V6'

```
dt2[, V6 := .SD[[V5]], by = 1:nrow(dt2)]
dt2
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1:  1 10  7  4  3  7
#2:  2 11  8  5  2 11
#3:  3 12  9  6  1  3
#4:  4  1 10  7  4  7
#5:  5  2 11  8  4  8
#6:  6  3 12  9  3 12
#7:  7  4  1 10  3  1
#8:  8  5  2 11  1  8
#9:  9  6  3 12  2  6
```

---

In `base R`, we use `row/column` indexing

```
setDF(dt2)
dt2$V6 <- dt2[cbind(seq_len(nrow(dt2)), dt2$V5)]
```

Comment: wow! that was so elegant. Perhaps for the benefit of all @akrun could you kindly explain in your data.table solution above, how does the  `1:nrow(dt2)` interact with `.SD` to produce the desireed output. Suggest adding the argument names too eg. `by=` if that is applicable. Thanks.

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra  Whenever you used a single index `df[[1]]` or `df[[2]]`, it extract that column.  As we have 9 column index, we group that row index, and then do the `[[` .  The `[[` will only a single element

Comment: `by=V5` should be a lot more efficient, I guess... can't find the dupe, but I'm sure I've seen that answered for the "select column by name" variant of this.